# Get the print confirmation from printer in C# i.e is succesfully printed or failed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, window

How to Get the print confirmation message from printer in C# i.e is
 successfully printed or Not?

Comment: Hi Guys, as per my task requirement i need solution above task ASAP. any one have idea or sample code then please share with us, Thanks in advance, God Bless you guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Print Job Status using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954929/how-to-get-print-job-status-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am working in kiosk application there i need confirmation from printer if print successfully done or not? i was search on Google but still not find any code or solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will depend on how you are printing, however...

This is pretty good library which I use:
https://printqueuewatch.codeplex.com/

```
printQueueWatch.AddPrinter(printDlg.PrintQueue.FullName)
AddHandler printQueueWatch.JobSet, AddressOf printQueueMonitor_PrintJobStatusChanged
AddHandler printQueueWatch.JobDeleted, AddressOf printQueueMonitor_PrintJobStatusChanged
```

Its not perfect, I've tweeked it a little here and there for my own needs but is the best free one I've found

Comment: i was try this but did not find solution of my above problem, can we use PrintSystemJobInfo C#, any idea for above problem please help me its urgent to me?

Comment: for printing i am using PrintDocument class? , i was try use PrintSystemJobInfo class for solve my problem but did not find any solution yet, so anyone know anything regarding that, then it's great help.