# Checking print job status with Winspool Drv

Tags: c#, printing, console-application, print-spooler-api

recently I was testing printing using winspool drv and I managed to be able to print successfully through a string (extracted from prn file). Now I want to check the status of my print job. I have read the winspool api [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions) but there isn't much of C# examples, so I am kind of lost.
I chanced upon this [link](http://delradiesdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/accessing-printer-status-using-winspool.html) and I am facing issues implementing it .

This is my current code

```
  #region Send to Printer
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern Boolean SetDefaultPrinter(String name);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            if (hPrinter.ToInt32() == 0)
                return false; //Printer not found!!
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    } public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        bool bSuccess = false;
        try
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[szString.Length];
            //your unmanaged pointer
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            //read content to array 

            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(szString);
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(bytes).ToArray();
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bytes.Length);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, bytes.Length);
            //send the unmanage bytes to the printer
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, bytes.Length);
            //Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { string s = ex.Message.ToString(); }
        return bSuccess;


    }
```

to call the method

```
 SendStringToPrinter(printername, prnstring);
```

Appreciate if anyone could help thx!

Answer (score 1):

In the code you already have, [StartDocPrinter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/startdocprinter) returns a job ID you can query using [GetJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/getjob).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6954929/313445) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563788/313445) for possibly useful info.